# text to facts for Inference Engine

Tags: artificial-intelligence, nlp, data-mining, inference

I am looking for a program or algorithm that will analyze text and produce facts/rules from it that can be fed to an inference engine for question answering. Are there any good commercial or open source solution for this available?

If not what algorithms should I be looking at, to try and code a solution myself.

Answer (score 2):

See one of the tools under [Attempto Tools](http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch/site/tools/) if some fit your requirements. It uses a controlled English.

Answer (score 1):

- http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software.php?software=infoextraction
- http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/web/competition.html
- http://www.kdnuggets.com/software/text.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction#Free_or_Open_Source_Information_Extraction_Software_or_Services

Answer (score 1):

[Try this- Apache Open NLP](http://incubator.apache.org/opennlp/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/manual/opennlp.html).